# spring cloud hystrix fallbackfactory

Tags: java, spring

when i study spring cloud feign with hystrix, have a problem, that
if i use LOGGER.info("**** {}", cause.getMessage()), the fallback is not work, UserFeignClient#findById(Long) timed-out and fallback failed. But if i remove cause.getMessage(), fallback is ok. Why?

```
public class UserFeignFallBackFactory implements FallbackFactory<UserFeignClient> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserFeignFallBackFactory.class);

    @Override
    public UserFeignClient create(Throwable cause) {
        LOGGER.info("call UserFeignClient error, error msg is : {}");
        return new UserFeignClientEx() {
            @Override
            public User findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
                return new User(-1L, null, null, (short) 20);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3oPr.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
public class UserFeignFallBackFactory implements FallbackFactory<UserFeignClient> {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserFeignFallBackFactory.class);

@Override
public UserFeignClient create(Throwable cause) {

    return new UserFeignClientEx() {
        @Override
        public User findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
            LOGGER.info("call UserFeignClient error, error msg is : {}");
            return new User(-1L, null, null, (short) 20);
        }
    };
}
}
```